# recv function hangs the program before being called

Tags: c, freeze, recv

Let's say i have

```
while(1){
    printf something
    printf something else
    recv(....);}
```

I know that recv is supposed to wait for something to be send,so it's normal to hang the console until then.But recv hangs the program before reaching it's line.For example if i run any program like this,the two printfs before it never happen

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Does your program compile without any errors? There might be anything else which is not allowing the code to reach till `while`. Also if you tag the programming language in your question, you could get some better responses.

Comment: yep,no errors at all.and the languange is C

Comment: Can you show your original piece of code?

Comment: How could code that has not been executed yet cause any effect on a program? I think your conclusions/assumptions need to be re-examined. As suggested in at least one answer below, possibly the output from `printf()` is not being flushed to the terminal - this would be a very likely situation if your `printf()` data (either from the format string or one of the data being formatted) does not include a newline...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the `printf` are happening, it's just that the console output is not being flushed. If you really need the output to be printed, you should consider using fflush: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/.

Comment: this seems to have worked ,i put fflush(stdout) after every printf placed around the recv functions.So is this a problem with my code or is wierd behavior caused by how C is designed?

Comment: This is nothing to do with your code, or really C either. It's a consequence of using buffered I/O, which is system dependent. You can control the buffering, with `setbuf` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setbuf/). Probably not advisable, because unbuffered I/O will likely be much slower (which is why buffered I/O is the default choice).